# xml import to sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mill operations.xsl"?>
<SetupSheetData>
  <ReportHeading>
    <Heading>Setup Sheet</Heading>
  </ReportHeading>
  <Data>
    <rep_Doc Unit="Inches" a3AxisPart="0.001" Spline="0.001" FacetRegen="0.000" ConfigurationComment="____________________" ConfigurationName="____________________" ConfigurationNameCW="Mill - Inch- 0 [  ]"/>
    <rep_MchParams MchName="Mill - Inch" MchDesc="Sample Milling Machine" MchDuty="Medium duty" MchType="This function has not been implemented for models with multiple sheetmetal base features (some of which may be hidden)." MchController="M3Axis-Tutorial.CTL" MchNoOfAxis="Axis3" MchModeFor4_5x="Simultaneous" MaxFeedRate="650.000" MaxSpindleSpeed="12000.000" MchToolPos="20" MchSpindleTaper="CT 40" MchHorsePower="30.000" MchTableTravelX="50.000" MchTableTravelY="20.000" MchTableTravelZ="25.000" MchToolCribId="5" MchDefMch="1" MchAvgToolChangeTime="0.200" MchRapidFeedRate="1000.000" MchAvgIndexTime="0.050" MchMode4_5xDesc="Simultaneous" MchNoAxisDesc="None" MchTypeDesc="Mill" MchToolCribPriority="1" MchUseToolCribToolsOnly="0" MchRetractDistance="10.000" MchDisplayCutCompFirstMove="0" MchOriginOffsetMethod="UseOpsetupTR" MchTotalMachiningTimeOfMachine="0.748"/>
    <rep_MchPosting DefineCoolantFrom="POST" DefineDiaLenOffsetFrom="POST" PostDirPath="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\Machining Testing for suppressed features\">
      <Param Name="Program number" Value="1"/>
      <Param Name="Part Thickness" Value="25.40000mm"/>
      <Param Name="5axis Arc Deviation" Value="0.02540mm"/>
    </rep_MchPosting>
    <rep_WorkPiece WorkPieceOriginX="0.000" WorkPieceOriginY="0.000" WorkPieceOriginZ="0.000" WorkPieceLength="2.065" WorkPieceWidth="0.800" WorkPieceHeight="118.234" WorkPieceOffset="0.000" WorkPieceTypeName="____________________" WorkPieceMaterial="6061-T6" WorkPieceStockGroupName="Aluminum Alloys" WorkPieceUnitsConvertFactor="-2"/>
    <rep_ConfigInfo>
      <Param Name="LinTol0Plc" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="LinTol1Plc" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="LinTol2Plc" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="Revision" Value="05" EvaluatedValue="05"/>
      <Param Name="Author" Value="debarrid" EvaluatedValue="debarrid"/>
      <Param Name="Description2" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="MaterialThickness" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionApprovedByHistory" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionApprovedDate" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionApprovedDateHistory" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionByHistory" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionNoteHistory" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionNumberHistory" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="Type" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="Apply Material to All Configurations" Value="Yes" EvaluatedValue="Yes"/>
      <Param Name="Project" Value="A-PARTS" EvaluatedValue="A-PARTS"/>
      <Param Name="Description" Value="FULL HEIGHT DOOR STOP EXTRUSION PROFILE" EvaluatedValue="FULL HEIGHT DOOR STOP EXTRUSION PROFILE"/>
      <Param Name="Finish" Value="SEE DWG. L05-0522" EvaluatedValue="SEE DWG. L05-0522"/>
      <Param Name="MakeFrom" Value="RAW MATERIAL" EvaluatedValue="RAW MATERIAL"/>
      <Param Name="DrawnBy" Value="Genadij M" EvaluatedValue="Genadij M"/>
      <Param Name="DrawnDate" Value="May 09, 07" EvaluatedValue="May 09, 07"/>
      <Param Name="ApprovedBy" Value="Genadij M" EvaluatedValue="Genadij M"/>
      <Param Name="ApprovedDate" Value="May 09, 07" EvaluatedValue="May 09, 07"/>
      <Param Name="LinTol3Plc" Value="±0.015" EvaluatedValue="±0.015"/>
      <Param Name="Angular" Value="±1" EvaluatedValue="±1"/>
      <Param Name="UserDefined1" Value="____________________"/>
      <Param Name="UserDefined2" Value="STANDARD" EvaluatedValue="STANDARD"/>
      <Param Name="Number" Value="10-023" EvaluatedValue="10-023"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionBy" Value="PS" EvaluatedValue="PS"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionDate" Value="Dec 19, 07" EvaluatedValue="Dec 19, 07"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionApprovedBy" Value="ZB" EvaluatedValue="ZB"/>
      <Param Name="RevisionNote" Value="CHANGED FINISH WAS &quot;CLEAR ANNOZIDED&quot; ONLY;" EvaluatedValue="CHANGED FINISH WAS &quot;CLEAR ANNOZIDED&quot; ONLY;"/>
      <Param Name="Material" Value="&quot;SW-Material@A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT&quot;" EvaluatedValue="ALUMINUM 6063-T5"/>
      <Param Name="DesignType" Value="Standard" EvaluatedValue="Standard"/>
      <Param Name="PartNumberStock" Value="A21-0605-X" EvaluatedValue="A21-0605-X"/>
      <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Post processor" Value="M3Axis-Tutorial.CTL" EvaluatedValue="M3Axis-Tutorial.CTL"/>
      <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Machine" Value="Mill - Inch" EvaluatedValue="Mill - Inch"/>
      <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Gcode file path" Value="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\Machining Testing for suppressed features\A23-3249L-X-BEN.txt" EvaluatedValue="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\Machining Testing for suppressed features\A23-3249L-X-BEN.txt"/>
      <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Created date" Value="01/13/2020::10:37" EvaluatedValue="01/13/2020::10:37"/>
      <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Post file size" Value="951 bytes" EvaluatedValue="951 bytes"/>
      <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Created by" Value="BConners" EvaluatedValue="BConners"/>
    </rep_ConfigInfo>
    <rep_CustomInfo CustomInfoMode="1" CustomInfoCompany="____________________" CustomInfoPartFile="A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT" Date="2020-01-20" Time="37:20 AM" CustomInfoDateTime="2020-01-20  9:37:20 AM" PartPath="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT" ImagePath="C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS CAM\lang\English\Setup_Sheet_Images\A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles\" CustomInfoCheckedBy="____________________" CustinfoClient="____________________" CustomInfoDateComplete="____________________" CustomInfoDepartment="____________________" CustomInfoDestination="____________________" CustomInfoDisposition="____________________" CustomInfoDevision="____________________" CustomInfoDocumentNumber="____________________" CustomInfoEditor="____________________" CustomInfoForwardedTo="____________________" CustomInfoGroup="____________________" CustomInfoLanguage="____________________" CustomInfoMailStop="____________________" CustomInfoMatter="____________________" CustomInfoOffice="____________________" CustomInfoOwner="____________________" CustomInfoProject="A-PARTS" CustomInfoPublisher="____________________" CustomInfoPurpose="____________________" CustomInfoReceivedfrom="____________________" CustomInfoReceivedBy="____________________" CustomInfoRecordDate="____________________" CustomInfoReference="____________________" CustomInfoSource="____________________" CustomInfoStatus="____________________" CustomInfoTelephoneNumber="____________________" CustomInfoTypist="____________________" CustomInfoCompanyName="____________________" CustomInfoProgrammer="____________________" CustomInfoPartNo="____________________" CustomInfoRevision="05" CustomInfoManufacturingApproval="____________________" CustomInfoMFGAppDate="____________________" CustomInfoAuthor="____________________" CustomInfoKeywords="____________________" CustomInfoComments="____________________" CustomInfoTitle="____________________" CustomInfoSubject="____________________" CustomInfoCreated="2006-05-09 5:03:30 PM" CustomInfoLastSaved="2020-01-13 10:37:59 AM" CustomInfoLastSavedBy="BConners"/>
```

I have an external .xml file that I would like to import some of the values into an sql table. I am new to sql programming but have attempted to write some code. The .xml file is a little different from some sample .xml files I have seen and I cannot get any of the values to populate the sql table. It identifies that there are 3 instances of the mill operations that I need, but there are no values being fed back to the table (just 3 blank rows). It seems in the .xml the value for the element is a huge string or something along those lines. I will attach a sample of the xml and the code I have written. Your help is much appreciated.

```html
 </MillOperation>
      <MillOperation>
        <rep_Operation OperationName="Countersink1" Comment="____________________" Description="COUNTERSINK" NoOfOPerations="5" OpNumber="3" OperationID="277"/>
        <rep_MillOperParams ZFeedRate="22.643" MillSpindleSpeed="4528.658" SpindleDirection="CW" CounterSinkType="Spot Drilling" FirstPeckAmt="0.200" SubPeckAmt="0.100" RapidPlaneDist="1.000" ClearPlaneDist="0.100" Dwell="1.000" RapidPlaneType="Top of Stock" RetractType="Rapid Plane" FirstCutFrom="Top of Feature" Offset="0.000" OptimizationMethod="Upper Left" LastClosest="0" XYFeedRate="N.A." MinToolProtusionLength="N.A." CuttingSpeed="598.473"/>
        <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="18" ToolStnNoSub="0" ToolStnID="____________________" ToolName="T18 - 5/8 X 90 Countersink" ToolComment="5/8 HSS 90DEG 4FL COUNTERSINK" ToolMaterial="HSS" CombId="____________________" ToolUsage="1" LengthOffset="1.000" DiameterOffset="1.000"/>
        <rep_MillToolParams SizeDesignation="5/8 X 90" CutDia="0.625" OverAllLen="2.250" CounterSinkAngle="90.000" ShankDia="0.375" EndDia="0.000" ShoulderLen="0.625" NoOfTeeth="4" Protrusion="1.500" HandofCut="RIGHT HAND" Material="HSS" Comment="5/8 HSS 90DEG 4FL COUNTERSINK" MillToolCoolant="Flood" ToolImagePath="ToolsImages\CounterSink.bmp"/>
        <rep_MillHolderLibrary HolderNumber="Default" HolderComment="____________________" HolderShape="Basic" HolderType="None" HolderSpec="None" TopDia="3.000" BottomDia="1.500" OverallLen="4.000" BottomLen="1.500" UserDefinedName="None" MillTurn="1"/>
        <rep_ToolImagePath ToolImagePath="ToolsImages\Setup_1_Operation_3.bmp"/>
        <rep_Posting>
          <Param Name="Absolute Incremental" Value="Absolute"/>
          <Param Name="Coolant" Value="Flood"/>
        </rep_Posting>
        <rep_Feature MachDepth="0.178" FeatureName="Countersink Hole Group1 [Drill] [Sub9]"/>
        <rep_Relation RelationMachDepth="0.178" RelationTlpLen="124.724" RelationTime="0.228" MinX="0.732" MinY="-54.883" MinZ="-0.178" MaxX="0.732" MaxY="57.117" MaxZ="1.000" StartComment="____________________" EndComment="____________________" OpName="Countersink1" ToolStn="18" ZDepth="0.178" MachiningDepth="0.178" RadialTipCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000" RadialCenterCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000" DiameterTipCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000" DiameterCenterCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.732500 , 57.117000 , 0.100000" GageOffsetX="0.000" GageOffsetY="0.000" GageOffsetZ="5.500"/>
      </MillOperation>
    </MillSetupSheetAttr>
```

```html
USE FFGD
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('FFGD.dbo.CAMWORKS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE FFGD.dbo.CAMWORKS
GO
 
CREATE TABLE FFGD.dbo.CAMWORKS
(
    OpNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 OperationName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 FeatureName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 RelationTlpLen varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 MillSpindleSpeed varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 ZFeedRate varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 ToolName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 ToolStnNo varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 RelationTime varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 
)
GO


INSERT INTO FFGD.dbo.CAMWORKS (OpNumber, OperationName, FeatureName, RelationTlpLen, MillSpindleSpeed, ZFeedRate, ToolName, ToolStnNo, RelationTime)
SELECT
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('OpNumber').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('OperationName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('FeatureName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('RelationTlpLen').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('MillSpindleSpeed').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('ZFeedRate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('ToolName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('ToolStnNo').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
   MY_XML.MillOperation.query('RelationTime').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
   
   
   
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\BConn\Desktop\CamworksReport.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('SetupSheetData/Data/MillSetupSheetAttr/MillOperation') AS MY_XML (MillOperation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it correctly. You need to specify correct element name and its child attribute in the XPath expressions. Also, it is better to use exact data types instead of the generic VARCHAR(100).

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupSheetData>
    <ReportHeading>
        <Heading>Setup Sheet</Heading>
    </ReportHeading>
    <Data>
        <rep_Doc Unit="Inches" a3AxisPart="0.001" Spline="0.001" FacetRegen="0.000"
                 ConfigurationComment="____________________"
                 ConfigurationName="____________________" ConfigurationNameCW="Mill - Inch- 0 [  ]"/>
        <rep_MchParams MchName="Mill - Inch" MchDesc="Sample Milling Machine" MchDuty="Medium duty"
                       MchType="This function has not been implemented for models with multiple sheetmetal base features (some of which may be hidden)."
                       MchController="M3Axis-Tutorial.CTL" MchNoOfAxis="Axis3"
                       MchModeFor4_5x="Simultaneous" MaxFeedRate="650.000"
                       MaxSpindleSpeed="12000.000" MchToolPos="20" MchSpindleTaper="CT 40"
                       MchHorsePower="30.000" MchTableTravelX="50.000" MchTableTravelY="20.000"
                       MchTableTravelZ="25.000" MchToolCribId="5" MchDefMch="1"
                       MchAvgToolChangeTime="0.200" MchRapidFeedRate="1000.000"
                       MchAvgIndexTime="0.050" MchMode4_5xDesc="Simultaneous" MchNoAxisDesc="None"
                       MchTypeDesc="Mill" MchToolCribPriority="1" MchUseToolCribToolsOnly="0"
                       MchRetractDistance="10.000" MchDisplayCutCompFirstMove="0"
                       MchOriginOffsetMethod="UseOpsetupTR" MchTotalMachiningTimeOfMachine="0.748"/>
        <rep_MchPosting DefineCoolantFrom="POST" DefineDiaLenOffsetFrom="POST"
                        PostDirPath="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\Machining Testing for suppressed features\">
            <Param Name="Program number" Value="1"/>
            <Param Name="Part Thickness" Value="25.40000mm"/>
            <Param Name="5axis Arc Deviation" Value="0.02540mm"/>
        </rep_MchPosting>
        <rep_WorkPiece WorkPieceOriginX="0.000" WorkPieceOriginY="0.000" WorkPieceOriginZ="0.000"
                       WorkPieceLength="2.065" WorkPieceWidth="0.800" WorkPieceHeight="118.234"
                       WorkPieceOffset="0.000" WorkPieceTypeName="____________________"
                       WorkPieceMaterial="6061-T6" WorkPieceStockGroupName="Aluminum Alloys"
                       WorkPieceUnitsConvertFactor="-2"/>
        <rep_ConfigInfo>
            <Param Name="LinTol0Plc" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="LinTol1Plc" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="LinTol2Plc" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="Revision" Value="05" EvaluatedValue="05"/>
            <Param Name="Author" Value="debarrid" EvaluatedValue="debarrid"/>
            <Param Name="Description2" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="MaterialThickness" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionApprovedByHistory" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionApprovedDate" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionApprovedDateHistory" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionByHistory" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionNoteHistory" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionNumberHistory" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="Type" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="Apply Material to All Configurations" Value="Yes" EvaluatedValue="Yes"/>
            <Param Name="Project" Value="A-PARTS" EvaluatedValue="A-PARTS"/>
            <Param Name="Description" Value="FULL HEIGHT DOOR STOP EXTRUSION PROFILE"
                   EvaluatedValue="FULL HEIGHT DOOR STOP EXTRUSION PROFILE"/>
            <Param Name="Finish" Value="SEE DWG. L05-0522" EvaluatedValue="SEE DWG. L05-0522"/>
            <Param Name="MakeFrom" Value="RAW MATERIAL" EvaluatedValue="RAW MATERIAL"/>
            <Param Name="DrawnBy" Value="Genadij M" EvaluatedValue="Genadij M"/>
            <Param Name="DrawnDate" Value="May 09, 07" EvaluatedValue="May 09, 07"/>
            <Param Name="ApprovedBy" Value="Genadij M" EvaluatedValue="Genadij M"/>
            <Param Name="ApprovedDate" Value="May 09, 07" EvaluatedValue="May 09, 07"/>
            <Param Name="LinTol3Plc" Value="±0.015" EvaluatedValue="±0.015"/>
            <Param Name="Angular" Value="±1" EvaluatedValue="±1"/>
            <Param Name="UserDefined1" Value="____________________"/>
            <Param Name="UserDefined2" Value="STANDARD" EvaluatedValue="STANDARD"/>
            <Param Name="Number" Value="10-023" EvaluatedValue="10-023"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionBy" Value="PS" EvaluatedValue="PS"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionDate" Value="Dec 19, 07" EvaluatedValue="Dec 19, 07"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionApprovedBy" Value="ZB" EvaluatedValue="ZB"/>
            <Param Name="RevisionNote" Value='CHANGED FINISH WAS "CLEAR ANNOZIDED" ONLY;'
                   EvaluatedValue='CHANGED FINISH WAS "CLEAR ANNOZIDED" ONLY;'/>
            <Param Name="Material" Value='"SW-Material@A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT"'
                   EvaluatedValue="ALUMINUM 6063-T5"/>
            <Param Name="DesignType" Value="Standard" EvaluatedValue="Standard"/>
            <Param Name="PartNumberStock" Value="A21-0605-X" EvaluatedValue="A21-0605-X"/>
            <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Post processor" Value="M3Axis-Tutorial.CTL"
                   EvaluatedValue="M3Axis-Tutorial.CTL"/>
            <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Machine" Value="Mill - Inch" EvaluatedValue="Mill - Inch"/>
            <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Gcode file path"
                   Value="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\Machining Testing for suppressed features\A23-3249L-X-BEN.txt"
                   EvaluatedValue="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\Machining Testing for suppressed features\A23-3249L-X-BEN.txt"/>
            <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Created date" Value="01/13/2020::10:37"
                   EvaluatedValue="01/13/2020::10:37"/>
            <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Post file size" Value="951 bytes" EvaluatedValue="951 bytes"/>
            <Param Name="SOLIDWORKS CAM Created by" Value="BConners" EvaluatedValue="BConners"/>
        </rep_ConfigInfo>
        <rep_CustomInfo CustomInfoMode="1" CustomInfoCompany="____________________"
                        CustomInfoPartFile="A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT" Date="2020-01-20"
                        Time="37:20 AM" CustomInfoDateTime="2020-01-20  9:37:20 AM"
                        PartPath="C:\Users\BConners\Desktop\A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT"
                        ImagePath="C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS Corp\SOLIDWORKS CAM\lang\English\Setup_Sheet_Images\A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles\"
                        CustomInfoCheckedBy="____________________"
                        CustinfoClient="____________________"
                        CustomInfoDateComplete="____________________"
                        CustomInfoDepartment="____________________"
                        CustomInfoDestination="____________________"
                        CustomInfoDisposition="____________________"
                        CustomInfoDevision="____________________"
                        CustomInfoDocumentNumber="____________________"
                        CustomInfoEditor="____________________"
                        CustomInfoForwardedTo="____________________"
                        CustomInfoGroup="____________________"
                        CustomInfoLanguage="____________________"
                        CustomInfoMailStop="____________________"
                        CustomInfoMatter="____________________"
                        CustomInfoOffice="____________________"
                        CustomInfoOwner="____________________" CustomInfoProject="A-PARTS"
                        CustomInfoPublisher="____________________"
                        CustomInfoPurpose="____________________"
                        CustomInfoReceivedfrom="____________________"
                        CustomInfoReceivedBy="____________________"
                        CustomInfoRecordDate="____________________"
                        CustomInfoReference="____________________"
                        CustomInfoSource="____________________"
                        CustomInfoStatus="____________________"
                        CustomInfoTelephoneNumber="____________________"
                        CustomInfoTypist="____________________"
                        CustomInfoCompanyName="____________________"
                        CustomInfoProgrammer="____________________"
                        CustomInfoPartNo="____________________" CustomInfoRevision="05"
                        CustomInfoManufacturingApproval="____________________"
                        CustomInfoMFGAppDate="____________________"
                        CustomInfoAuthor="____________________"
                        CustomInfoKeywords="____________________"
                        CustomInfoComments="____________________"
                        CustomInfoTitle="____________________"
                        CustomInfoSubject="____________________"
                        CustomInfoCreated="2006-05-09 5:03:30 PM"
                        CustomInfoLastSaved="2020-01-13 10:37:59 AM"
                        CustomInfoLastSavedBy="BConners"/>
        <MillSetupSheetAttr>
            <MillOperation>
                <rep_Operation OperationName="Countersink1" Comment="____________________"
                               Description="COUNTERSINK" NoOfOPerations="5" OpNumber="3"
                               OperationID="277"/>
                <rep_MillOperParams ZFeedRate="22.643" MillSpindleSpeed="4528.658"
                                    SpindleDirection="CW" CounterSinkType="Spot Drilling"
                                    FirstPeckAmt="0.200" SubPeckAmt="0.100" RapidPlaneDist="1.000"
                                    ClearPlaneDist="0.100" Dwell="1.000"
                                    RapidPlaneType="Top of Stock" RetractType="Rapid Plane"
                                    FirstCutFrom="Top of Feature" Offset="0.000"
                                    OptimizationMethod="Upper Left" LastClosest="0"
                                    XYFeedRate="N.A." MinToolProtusionLength="N.A."
                                    CuttingSpeed="598.473"/>
                <rep_Tool ToolStnNo="18" ToolStnNoSub="0" ToolStnID="____________________"
                          ToolName="T18 - 5/8 X 90 Countersink"
                          ToolComment="5/8 HSS 90DEG 4FL COUNTERSINK" ToolMaterial="HSS"
                          CombId="____________________" ToolUsage="1" LengthOffset="1.000"
                          DiameterOffset="1.000"/>
                <rep_MillToolParams SizeDesignation="5/8 X 90" CutDia="0.625" OverAllLen="2.250"
                                    CounterSinkAngle="90.000" ShankDia="0.375" EndDia="0.000"
                                    ShoulderLen="0.625" NoOfTeeth="4" Protrusion="1.500"
                                    HandofCut="RIGHT HAND" Material="HSS"
                                    Comment="5/8 HSS 90DEG 4FL COUNTERSINK" MillToolCoolant="Flood"
                                    ToolImagePath="ToolsImages\CounterSink.bmp"/>
                <rep_MillHolderLibrary HolderNumber="Default" HolderComment="____________________"
                                       HolderShape="Basic" HolderType="None" HolderSpec="None"
                                       TopDia="3.000" BottomDia="1.500" OverallLen="4.000"
                                       BottomLen="1.500" UserDefinedName="None" MillTurn="1"/>
                <rep_ToolImagePath ToolImagePath="ToolsImages\Setup_1_Operation_3.bmp"/>
                <rep_Posting>
                    <Param Name="Absolute Incremental" Value="Absolute"/>
                    <Param Name="Coolant" Value="Flood"/>
                </rep_Posting>
                <rep_Feature MachDepth="0.178" FeatureName="Countersink Hole Group1 [Drill] [Sub9]"/>
                <rep_Relation RelationMachDepth="0.178" RelationTlpLen="124.724"
                              RelationTime="0.228" MinX="0.732" MinY="-54.883" MinZ="-0.178"
                              MaxX="0.732" MaxY="57.117" MaxZ="1.000"
                              StartComment="____________________" EndComment="____________________"
                              OpName="Countersink1" ToolStn="18" ZDepth="0.178"
                              MachiningDepth="0.178"
                              RadialTipCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000"
                              RadialCenterCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000"
                              DiameterTipCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000"
                              DiameterCenterCoordinateDispalyPoint="0.732500 , 57.117000 , 0.100000"
                              GageOffsetX="0.000" GageOffsetY="0.000" GageOffsetZ="5.500"/>
            </MillOperation>
        </MillSetupSheetAttr>
    </Data>
</SetupSheetData>
```

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    CustomInfoPartFile VARCHAR(100),
    OpNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    OperationName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    FeatureName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    RelationTlpLen varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    MillSpindleSpeed varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ZFeedRate varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ToolName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ToolStnNo varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    RelationTime varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\CamworksReport.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomInfoPartFile, OpNumber, OperationName, FeatureName, RelationTlpLen, MillSpindleSpeed, ZFeedRate, ToolName, ToolStnNo, RelationTime)
SELECT c.value('(../../rep_CustomInfo/@CustomInfoPartFile)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [CustomInfoPartFile]
    , c.value('(rep_Operation/@OpNumber)[1]','INT') AS [OpNumber]
    , c.value('(rep_Operation/@OperationName)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [OperationName]
    , c.value('(rep_Feature/@FeatureName)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [FeatureName]
    , c.value('(rep_Relation/@RelationTlpLen)[1]','DECIMAL(10,3)') AS [RelationTlpLen]
    , c.value('(rep_MillOperParams/@MillSpindleSpeed)[1]','DECIMAL(10,3)') AS [MillSpindleSpeed]
    , c.value('(rep_MillOperParams/@ZFeedRate)[1]','DECIMAL(10,3)') AS [ZFeedRate]
    , c.value('(rep_Tool/@ToolName)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [ToolName]
    , c.value('(rep_Tool/@ToolStnNo)[1]','INT') AS [ToolStnNo]
    , c.value('(rep_Relation/@RelationTime)[1]','DECIMAL(10,3)') AS [RelationTime]
FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('(/SetupSheetData/Data/MillSetupSheetAttr/MillOperation)') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
+----------------------------------+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+----------------------------+-----------+--------------+
|        CustomInfoPartFile        | OpNumber | OperationName |              FeatureName               | RelationTlpLen | MillSpindleSpeed | ZFeedRate |          ToolName          | ToolStnNo | RelationTime |
+----------------------------------+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+----------------------------+-----------+--------------+
| A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT |        3 | Countersink1  | Countersink Hole Group1 [Drill] [Sub9] |        124.724 |         4528.658 |    22.643 | T18 - 5/8 X 90 Countersink |        18 |        0.228 |
+----------------------------------+----------+---------------+----------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+----------------------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: I tried your code, but my table is coming up empty for some reason. Changed the path for the xml location. I get the table headings but no data populating.

Comment: Ben, if you will try the answer in SSMS it is working as expected. You need to make two adjustments to make it working with your XML file. (1) Change fully qualified path to the XML file. (2) Modify **xmlData.nodes('(/MillSetupSheetAttr/MillOperation)') AS t(c);** XPath expression to match exactly your real XML file. Very possible as follows: **'/SetupSheetData/Data/MillSetupSheetAttr/MillOperation'**

Comment: Thank you! It worked great. One last thing, what would have to be written in the code to allow me to make another column in the new that would be populated with the same value taken from the XML. For example, all these machining options are for the same part and I need another column with this part number so I can use it later to do an inner join with another table that I already have.

Comment: Ben, it is not clear where the **'part number'** is in your XML. What is the name of the attribute? Please clarify.

Comment: </rep_ConfigInfo>, <rep_CustomInfo, CustomInfoPartFile="A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT". Sorry I had to give the element and attribute in this manner. Can't figure out the shortcut to post code in the comments.

Comment: Ben, the XML you provided in the OP doesn't contain any of it. Please modify your original post.

Comment: Sorry, I added the front end of the xml. If you scroll down to the last few lines the part number is listed there. </rep_ConfigInfo>, <rep_CustomInfo, CustomInfoPartFile="A23-3249L-X-SlotsAndHoles.SLDPRT"

Comment: Ben, still not clear. Do you have one input XMLs or Two?

Comment: Just one input xml. I just need that part number, to populate all entries for an added column. That part number would exist for the 3 entries that we derived out of the xml before.

Comment: I got it. I adjusted the answer to incorporate what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Ben, good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please mark it as answered. Let's connect on the LinkedIn.

Comment: Not sure how to mark it an answered. For sure, look me up on linkedin - Ben Conners last company I worked for was lovsuns - if there are many people with my name.

Comment: You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 

Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".

Comment: Is it possible to further this query, to use a trigger such that if sql sees an .xml file in a specified directory, it could run this query and update the table or or wipe the table and create a new one. I have not decided whether to wipe the table or update it as of yet for our company process?

Comment: Ben, it should be a more elaborate ETL process with at least 3 steps: (1) poll a directory for an XML file arrival. (2) Load process, answered here. With addition of INSERT/UPDATE via MERGE statement. (3) Moving an XML  file to an archive.

Comment: Thanks Yitzak. I looked into creating an SSIS package in visual studio using using filewatcher from the ssis toolbox which was an addin that I had found. It seemed to work well for dropping a file and then processing it and moving to a finished directory. I have to learn now how to add this ssis package to the sql server agent and schedule it etc. Thank you for the process stated above.

Comment: I have another question. I am having difficulty trying to extract a some info from a line in the xml I had previously given to you. I can't seem to hit the node to retrieve the info. At the very first pane at the beginning of this thread, im looking in the <rep_ConfigInfo> <Param Name="UserDefined2". Im trying to extract the EvaluatedValue from that entry. I just can't figure how to get to it. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just add the following line: **, c.value('(../../rep_ConfigInfo/Param[@Name="UserDefined2"]/@EvaluatedValue)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [SomeColumnName]**

Comment: Thank you very much - couldn't figure that out for the life of me.